# 14.04 --> 16.04 failed; apt (>= 1.0.1ubuntu2.13)' is not installed

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, updates, dependencies

(This question was not resolved. Due to time constraints Computer was restored to factory settings.)

I was attempting to upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04, but `apt` threw this error:

```
The required dependency 'apt (>= 1.0.1ubuntu2.13)' is not installed.
```

What does this mean, and how can I fix it?

When I type in the command apt-cache policy apt

```
Shageenth@shageenth-Inspiron-3451:~$ apt-cache policy apt apt:
Installed: 1.0.1ubuntu2.11
Candidate: 1.0.1ubuntu2.11
Version table:
*** 1.0.1ubuntu2.11 0
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
1.0.1ubuntu2 0
500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 
Packages
```

The error happens when I run the command:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

and it produces the following:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [198 B]
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,265 kB]
Fetched 1,265 kB in 0s (0 B/s)
authenticate 'xenial.tar.gz' against 'xenial.tar.gz.gpg'
extracting 'xenial.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done

Required depends is not installed

The required dependency 'apt (>= 1.0.1ubuntu2.13)' is not installed.
```

Comment: I have deleted my answer now as I have found somebody more able to help who will post an answer soon.

Comment: I also have this problem – trying to upgrade my cubieboard (linaro port) and couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 50):

I've had the exact same problem today.
Make sure your version is the latest Ubuntu 14.04 version before the upgrade. (Ubuntu 14.04.4 at this time)

Mine was stuck to Ubuntu 14.04.3 due to a bad mirror.

So first run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Make sure the version is now Ubuntu 14.04.4 (update September 2016 : **Ubuntu 14.04.5**).

`cat /etc/lsb-release`

And start Ubuntu 16.04 installation with

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Comment: My version is 14.04 already

Comment: The minor version (see .3 and .4 after 14.04) is the important point. If you already had 14.04.4, the apt and dpkg would be the right version already.

Comment: This is the correct answer, although the version is now 14.0.4.5

Comment: I see DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS" in my machine, but still giving the same error.

Comment: In the "Software & Updates" manager, make sure that "Important security updates" and "Recommended updates" are checked if the commands in the answer aren't working for you.

Comment: Doesn't work. The other answer does.

Comment: I also had a bad mirror, did a `sed -i -e "s/us\./fr\./g" /etc/apt/sources.list` and worked like a charm.

Comment: @PatrickBrinich-Langlois All of them are disabled and unchecked.

Comment: This is what is working for me at the end for upgrade from 14.04.5 LTS to 16.04 LTS:: `sudo do-release-upgrade -c && do-release-upgrade`

Answer (score 12):

Best to always update through the normal procedures of:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

---

If the above fails, then you can step manually through the following.  This question is outdated, but you can just change the version numbers as the links should still be the same.

To upgrade your version of `apt` from a terminal window, type in the following:

```
sudo apt-get download apt
```

if the above doesn't work, you can also download it with `wget` by running the following line:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.17_amd64.deb
```

then type in

```
sudo dpkg -i apt*.deb
```

---

Just tried this on my system here.  Here is the output:

```
terrance@terrance-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get download apt
[sudo] password for terrance: 
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main apt amd64 1.0.1ubuntu2.17 [954 kB]
Fetched 954 kB in 0s (1,127 kB/s)
terrance@terrance-VirtualBox:~$ ls
apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.17_amd64.deb  Documents  examples.desktop  Pictures  Templates
Desktop                        Downloads  Music             Public    Videos
terrance@terrance-VirtualBox:~$ sudo dpkg -i apt*.deb
(Reading database ... 168376 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.17_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apt (1.0.1ubuntu2.17) over (1.0.1ubuntu2.11) ...
Setting up apt (1.0.1ubuntu2.17) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.7) ...
```

---

If After the steps described you see a fail due to a missing dpkg dependency you can just finish by repeating the steps with dpkg and ..

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.18.24ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i dpkg_1.18.24ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

All of the packages that are available to Ubuntu can be found here:

http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/

Comment: when I type in sudo apt-get download apt, I get E: Can't find a source to download version '1.0.1ubuntu2.11' of 'apt:amd64'

Comment: @ShageenthSandrakumar I updated for wget to download it directly too if the apt-get does not work.

Comment: Now after rerunning the upgrade, I get the following error: The required dependency 'dpkg (>= 1.17.5ubuntu5.6)' is not installed.

Comment: @ShageenthSandrakumar Hmmmm, without dpkg this may not be possible with the current installation.  I'm looking into other solutions.

Comment: @ShageenthSandrakumar Does `sudo apt-get install dpkg` work?

Comment: Yes it did work. But my update still give me the error above. For some reason I'm also having similar trouble when trying to download ROS indigo on my laptop giving me similar error of broken packagies

Comment: @ShageenthSandrakumar I know you mentioned it with Paranoid Panda when he was helping you, but what happens when you run `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: Where to get the `armv7l` version of that package?

Comment: In case you're looking for the ARM version (Linaro) – `http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.13_armhf.deb`

Comment: This came up for me. `wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.13_amd64.deb`   now needs to be   2.17 not 2.13

Comment: I wish I could award you a bounty for that...

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix...Which has worked for me...

Open your Synaptic Package manager type "apt" in search box that will show you the current installed version  of apt lets assume "1.0.1ubuntu1.13" just right click on it and click mark for upgrade then click apply button at the top.

after upgrade..

Make sure to close the synaptic package manager before going to run your

final command

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

and it should work..

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message and a very simple

`apt-get update
apt-get upgrade`

solved it. The other answers are wildly innacurate -- for example the one talking about moving Ubuntu 14.04.3 to 14.04.4 via `dist-upgrade` -- but `dist-upgrade` moves to the next Ubuntu version, not minors. Minors are just a released collection of specific package versions anyways, simply by keeping your packages up to date you get at least those versions or newer. Do not run `dist-upgrade` unless you know what you are doing.