# UPDATE: Upgrade to 16 Failure + Google Chrome is not working anymore

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 16.04, updates, google-chrome

I've been trying to upgrade my Ubutnu from 14.04 to 16.04, when I click on upgrading the system is shows me this error:

```
The required dependency 'apt (>= 1.0.1ubuntu2.13)' is not installed
```

I tried the sol here, but it didnt work with me:
[14.04 --> 16.04 failed; apt (>= 1.0.1ubuntu2.13)' is not installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777013/14-04-16-04-failed-apt-1-0-1ubuntu2-13-is-not-installed).

UPDATE:

I fixed the mentioned problem above, but still, I cannot upgrade to 16.04. Now is shows me this:

```
Error during update 

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of network problem, please check your network connection and retry. 

W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80] , W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/stable/main/binary-i386/Packages 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80] , E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Also, Google Chrome stopped working all of sudden. When I try to open it using the terminal, it shows me:

```
[8984:9017:0728/230608:ERROR:nss_util.cc(744)] Error initializing NSS with a persistent database (sql:/home/maldini/.pki/nssdb): libsoftokn3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[8984:9017:0728/230608:ERROR:nss_util.cc(212)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: NSS error code: -5925
[8984:9017:0728/230608:FATAL:nss_util.cc(214)] nss_error=-5925, os_error=0
```

Aborted (core dumped)

I removed and "purged" the program and then re-install again. I tried removing all the caches and config files. They all didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does http://askubuntu.com/questions/801838/google-chrome-error-error-initializing-nss-without-a-persistent-database help?

Comment: No. I did what they mentioned; didn't work with me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when im running google-chrome from terminal,

I found that it needed a new version of NSS: Chrome 62 need NSS>=3.26. So I installed libnss3.

```
$google-chrome

[6999:7036:1113/200616.549496:FATAL:nss_util.cc(632)] NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required. Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

#sudo apt-get install --reinstall libnss3

and it worked for me