# Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS --> 16.04 failed; apt (>= 1.0.1ubuntu2.13)' is not installed

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade

I want to upgrade `Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS` to `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`.

First I run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Then I checked Ubuntu running version:

```
cat /etc/lsb-release

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
```

and then I started Ubuntu 16.04 installation with

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

which threw the following error:

```
The required dependency 'apt (>= 1.0.1ubuntu2.13)' is not installed.
```

I know that first I need to upgrade `Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS` to `Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS` and then to `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`. But unable to upgrade `Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS` to `Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS`. I would highly appreciate if someone help me in this regard. Thanks

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get -y install apt
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

But still getting the same error. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Waow.I didn't know about this method.I thought the upgrade will only be done when the software updater states that a new version of ubuntu is ready..

Comment: Thanks @Anwar for pointing to a solution. But still I'm getting the same error. Please see my edits and suggest any solution if you can. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the solutions there?

Comment: Yes, @Anwar. I tried the solution given in the link but still getting the same error. Any thoughts, please. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Anwar, would you suggest any solution to my problem. Thanks

Comment: Check [this question and it's solution](http://askubuntu.com/questions/777013/14-04-16-04-failed-apt-1-0-1ubuntu2-13-is-not-installed). It will be solved. Make sure you first upgraded to 14.04.4 using `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. Then do the `do-release-upgrade`

Comment: Hi @Anwar, I tried every method. Still getting the same problem. Would appreciate if you help me. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 can we discuss the topic [in this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44292/discussion-between-anwar-and-myaseen208)?